# Find text and value with Excel 2010

Tags: excel-2010

Is it possible to find a cell that contains "text", and return the value of the cell next to it (one column to the right)?

Answer (score 0):

The built-in function VLOOKUP() does exactly what you want.

=vlookup(text, where_to_look, offset_to_the_right)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Comment: Thanks Valentin. I tried to look up "GLFOX" to return the numeric value in the cell to the right of "GLFOX" with:  =VLOOKUP("GLFOX",A2:H200,2,FALSE)  and it returned #N/A ?